# Space between # and ! in shebang (# !/usr/bin/ksh)

Tags: shell, ksh, shebang

I am writing a Korn shell script that involves process substitution using `< <()`, like this:

```
array=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' x;do
    array+=( "$x" )
done < <(some command)
```

This is trying to insert into `array` all string returned by `some command`. The curious thing is that this works when my shebang looks like this:

`# !/usr/bin/ksh`

which is of course unusual (notice the space between `#` and `!`). On the other hand, when my shebang looks like `#!/usr/bin/ksh` (the right way, apparently), this script fails with the error `syntax error: '< ' unexpected`. Why is this? What difference does having a space in the shebang mean? Google gave me several answers saying that a space between `!#` and `!/usr...` is okay, but nothing regarding a space between `!` and `#`.

Answer (score 2):

#### `# !` is an invalid shebang, and entirely ignored. Behavior of a script with no shebang depends on how you invoke it.

If invoked from a shell: Some shells use `/bin/sh` to run such scripts; others use themselves for the purpose. Presumably the shell you're interactively using when testing this (and finding the script to work only with an invalid shebang) is in the latter set, so your script is *actually* being run with bash, or otherwise your active interactive shell at the time.

If invoked without a shell: Most operating systems will refuse to execute such a binary.

---

#### Real David Korn ksh93 supports process substitution correctly, but some 3rd-party clones and ancient ksh implementations don't.

If you're going to use ksh, using genuine David Korn ksh93 (not mksh, pdksh, or another 3rd-party clone) is strongly preferred, and (to your immediate point) will ensure process substitution support.

Comment: It's also possible that `/bin/sh` is a symlink to ksh, or to some shell that implements the features used by the script.

Comment: I installed ksh through Cygwin, which offers mksh, which doesn't support process substitution. Would it be possible for you to point me toward a guide on how to install ksh93 on windows (sorry, noob here).

Comment: From a very quick bit of googling, https://github.com/att/ast looks like your best bet.